# fql multiquery returns uknown error code

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, oauth-2.0, fql.multiquery

My multiquery function worked prior to the use of oauth 2.0 as of DEC 13th. I send GET requests to https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.multiquery?access_token=....

Do I have to change the mechanism by which i fetch data? is the new oauth token have to be handled differently and passed differently?

multiquery params 
{'query1':'select eid from event_member where uid = and start_time > 1313533038','query2':'select eid,uid,rsvp_status from event_member where (rsvp_status=\"attending\" or rsvp_status=\"maybe_attending\") and eid in (select eid from #query1)','query3':'select uid,name,sex,affiliations,birthday_date, relationship_status, meeting_sex, hs_info, education_history, work_history from user where uid in (select uid from #query2)','query4':'select event_type,event_subtype, start_time,end_time, name,tagline, description, eid, location, venue, privacy from event where eid in (select eid from #query1)'}

The Error I get is "Unknow error occured"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug for this. 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/236539819755426

To help get it solved quicker mark as repro and subscribe to it so you can get updates.